# Is there a way to skip the 'TimeSpan.FromSeconds' on the first run with a Periodic Timer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a controller that will make a call to get a OAuth2 Token. On the callback I want to start a periodic timer to refresh the token every x seconds/minutes.

The problem I am facing is on the callback, I need to wait for the amount of x seconds before getting redirected after getting the token. Is there a way or alternative way to achieve the method to run every x minutes without having to wait that amount on the initial run.

I have tried a few things ->

1. Setting the periodic timer in my callback function
2. Setting the periodic timer in a new method and calling it from my callback function. (without await it only runs once, and with await it does not redirect me.)

Here is my controller

```
using LicenseManagement.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Client;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Config;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Models;
using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Token;

namespace LicenseManagement.Controllers
{
    public class XeroOAuth2Controller : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IOptions<XeroConfiguration> XeroConfig;
        private readonly IXero _xero;
        public string xeroClientId;
        public XeroConfiguration xconfig;
        public XeroOAuth2Controller(IOptions<XeroConfiguration> config, ILogger<HomeController> logger,IXero xero)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.XeroConfig = config;
            _xero = xero;
            xconfig = new XeroConfiguration();
            xconfig.ClientId = "Secret";
            xconfig.ClientSecret = "Secret";
            xconfig.CallbackUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7182/XeroOAuth2/Callback"); //default for standard webapi template
            xconfig.Scope = "openid profile email files accounting.transactions accounting.transactions.read accounting.reports.read accounting.journals.read accounting.settings accounting.settings.read accounting.contacts accounting.contacts.read accounting.attachments accounting.attachments.read offline_access payroll.employees payroll.payruns payroll.payslip payroll.settings payroll.timesheets assets";
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);
            return Redirect(client.BuildLoginUri());
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Callback(string code,string state)
        {   
            var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);

            var accessToken = await client.RequestAccessTokenAsync(code);
            var tenants = await client.GetConnectionsAsync(accessToken);
            var tenantId = tenants.Select(t => t.TenantId).FirstOrDefault();
            _xero.CreateXeroToken(accessToken,tenantId);

            var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
            {
                await RefreshToken();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }

        public async Task GetContacts()
        {
            var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);
            var contactList =  await _xero.GetContacts();
            var companies = await _xero.SaveContactsFromXero(contactList);
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> RefreshToken()
        {
            var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);
            var token = await _xero.GetXeroToken();           

            var xeroToken = new XeroOAuth2Token
            {
                AccessToken = token.AccessToken,
                ExpiresAtUtc = token.ExpiresAtUtc,
                RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken,
                IdToken = token.IdToken
            };

            var newToken = await client.RefreshAccessTokenAsync(xeroToken);
            _xero.CreateXeroToken(newToken, token.TenantId);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

My callback method is 'Callback' and the method I want to run every x minutes is 'RefreshToken'

Comment: do/while instead of while? Or why not just use a `Task.Delay` in a loop?

Comment: Setting a timer and waiting for it on the web server is an unusual design to say the least. Are you unable to set a timer on the client side?

Comment: Call `refreshToken()` once prior to entering the loop? But how will that callback ever return something (or execute the `Redirect`)? The result of `WaitForNextTickAsync` will always be `true` unless you cancel the timer. But as the `timer` is local to that method the only place you can cancel it is from within that method (which doesn't happen)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your code. Is hard to see what your intent is, but having a timer or an infinite loop in a controller, as you have, is not a good idea.

Consider persisting your token to database, file or even some static variable (if you're sure you only need one, and only one, token). Then you check if you need to renew or request a new token before using it. If you really, truly, and definitely, require to keep the token alive for some unknown reason, you could consider a [background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) to perform the renewal.